# Отправка большого количества писем в PHP

Tags: postfix, exim, php, email

Нужно делать рассылку для сайта. До каких объемов писем можно удовлетворяться возможностями стандартного MTA типа Exim?

Просто решаю вопрос - нужно ли делать внутри приложения свою очередь писем и потом отправлять письма по крону, или стоит просто скармливать их MTA, а он уж сам очередь организует и будет ее обслуживать?

Сможет ли MTA продолжить обработку очереди после падения?

Comment: постфикс отлично справляется с большим объемом писем. стоит как корп.почтовик. за 8 лет падений небыло... `mailq` посмотреть очередь писем если что.

Comment: большие объемы это сколько? какие-то особые настройки нужны?

Comment: в секунду в среднем 3-5 писем +/-. настроек -- нет, ничего такого не надо. плюс на сервере стоят всякие postgrey, spamassassin, clamav, спамлисты, плюс самописный скрипт для обработки определенных команд... не тормозит, живет своей жизнью...

Answer (score 3):

Всегда лучше перебдеть, чем недобдеть.
Иногда ограничение срабатывает неожиданно и очень больно, особенно, если хостинг чей-то.
Узнайте у этого кого-то сколько максимум писем можно отправлять и отправляйте примерно на 10-20 меньше(на случай, если понадобится экстренно послать письмо).
Так что cron будет оптимальным, при том что очередь лучше строить в БД, где вы легко сможете отслеживать куда вы отправляли и как давно.

Comment: да, чтото я привык к своим серверам))) правильно подмечено, что необходимо у хостера узнавать про количества писем и договариваться с ним, если количества не удовлетворяют правилам хостинга...